# Access - Validation Based on ID and Date

Tags: validation, ms-access

I am constructing a small Access database for a food bank operation as a project for a class. The following is one of my tables:

Order(orderID, householdID, orderDate, deliverDate)

How would I go about setting data validation rules that only allow a household (householdID) to place one order (orderDate) per calendar month? Is this possible only with validation rules within this table?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Will need to use VBA, either in BeforeUpdate event of orderDate textbox or BeforeUpdate event of form. Could use DLookup() expression. Something like:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Not IsNull(DLookup("householdID", "Order", "Format([OrderDate], 'yyyymm')=" & Format(Me.tbxDate, "yyyymm"))) Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Household already has order for this month."
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
End If
End Sub
```

Might also be possible to use table BeforeChange data macro, however, I don't use macros of any type.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting the impression I really need to start learning VBA...